# How to start id on max and auto decrement in postgres

Tags: database, postgresql

How can i start a table with an id on max value and auto increment -1 on PostgreSQL?

I need to create a table with initial value on max int, and have to be an auto increment, but the auto increment have to be -1.

I know how to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE "external_sequence" ("id" int NOT NULL, "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT now(), "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT now(), CONSTRAINT "PK_119c50ca5604d166b77b8585a2c" PRIMARY KEY ("id"))
```

But in this case the table starts with id 1 and increment every row, i must start without set the number i don't know, mey a postgres function to start on max value and increment -1 every row.

Is this possible?

I'm trying to do this with node.js and typeorm, but i can use the query if it's necessary. I hope you can understand my poor english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE my_custom_sequence START WITH 2147483647 INCREMENT BY -1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 MINVALUE 1;

-- if you already have sequence want to modify:
-- alter sequence my_custom_sequence INCREMENT BY -1;
-- ALTER SEQUENCE my_custom_sequence RESTART WITH 2147483647;


CREATE TABLE tests (
  id integer not null default nextval('my_custom_sequence'),
  name VARCHAR ( 255 ) NOT NULL

);
insert into tests(name) values('first');
insert into tests(name) values('second');
insert into tests(name) values('third');

select * from tests;


     id     |  name  
------------+--------
 2147483647 | first
 2147483646 | second
 2147483645 | third
```

More info: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altersequence.html

Comment: it's possíble to set the restart value with some function?

Comment: I don't think you can do this with DDL. By the way I did update create sequence since you don't need restart you can define it on create sequence level

Comment: If i want a bigint id, i just need to change de start value? or do i have to set the data type?